# Showing that $\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx - \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy = d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to show that

$$
\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx - \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy = d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)
$$

but am having trouble figuring out exactly how to approach the problem. I've tried a few tricks with switching to polar coordinates or trying to make use of right triangles, but have had no luck. Could anyone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: You don't need polar or right triangles for this.

Comment: Do you know the derivative of $\operatorname{tan}^{-1}$?

Comment: This is not exactly true, because the LHS is defined in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{(0,0)\}$, while the RHS is defined in $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y\neq0\}$.

Answer (score 5):

Hint: 
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\tan^{-1}(t) = \frac{1}{1+t^2} $$
$$ d f(x,y) = \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y} dy $$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{y}{x^2+y^2} \, dx - \frac{x}{x^2+y^2} \, dy &=\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{y})^2+1}\frac{1}{y}dx+ \frac{1}{(\frac{x}{y})^2+1}(-\frac{x}{y^2}) dy\\
&=\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{y})^2+1}(\frac{1}{y}dx+(-\frac{x}{y^2})dy)\\
&=\frac{1}{(\frac{x}{y})^2+1}d(\frac{x}{y})\\
&= d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right)
\end{align}$$

Answer (score -1):

Using the Hint from above:
\begin{align}
d\left(\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)\right) &= \frac{\partial \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{\partial\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}\frac{\partial\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{\partial x} dx + \frac{\partial \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{\partial\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}\frac{\partial\left(\frac{x}{y}\right)}{\partial y} dy \\
&= \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}}\frac{1}{y}dx + \frac{1}{1+\frac{x^2}{y^2}}\left(-\frac{x}{y^2} \right)dy\\
&=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}dx-\frac{x}{y^2+x^2}dy
\end{align}